# Autocovariance of a Product of Zero-Mean, Wide-Sense Stationary Gaussian Random Process?

Tags: functions, stochastic-processes, covariance

If X(t) is a Wide-Sense-Stationary Gaussian Random Variable with zero mean, i.e. E[X(t)] = 0, how do you find the autocovariance of $Z(t) = X^2(t)$

I know that for a zero-mean Gaussian, the following applies:

[1234] = [12][34] + [13][24] + [14][23]